# java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException when reading propeties file

Tags: java

I have a method

```
   private Properties loadProperties() throws IOException {

        Properties configuration = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = getClass()
                .getResourceAsStream("/" + RESOURCE_FILE);
        configuration.load(inputStream);

        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }

        return configuration;
    }
```

this method loads properties from property file and returns it. However i build shaded jar from this project and adds the shaded jar to another project. When the project tries to execute this method, it throws :

> java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException

The project is running on windows machine so it should have filesystem. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with the "Windows FileSystem". You read a file from a jar file and JAVA requires that the jar file MUST contain the file you want to read. Make sure that

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass()
        .getResourceAsStream("/" + RESOURCE_FILE);
```

RESOURCE_FILE is correctly included in the JAR file. E.g. /dir/fileName where RESOURCE_FILE should be dir/fileName

Comment: the property file is included inside the jar file

Comment: The question is the HOW. It depends on the the manifest file or how you run the jar on the console to create your jar file. Suppose that your property file is prop.txt and resides in the classes directory together with java class: jar -cvf myjar.jar *.class prop.txt